# TabWidget without title

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm trying to make a ViewPager that slides between fragments and a custom slidebar, that shows which page is selected.

Should be like this:

[image: SlidingBar]

I don't want to display tab titles, only the bar itself.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by following a trick. Like as, First remove your all title from tab then make same color your layout and tablayout background.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
ViewPager
```

with

```
CircleIndicator - can be customized.
```

in gradle:

```
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.8@aar'
```

you can look sample [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1268)