# How to customize Bottom Navigation View?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm using `Bottom Navigation View` in my application. Everything is working fine but I need to add selected **purple** **line** when one of the items is selected.  How can I achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's Easy, 
Create a color folder in resource and paste the below xml
nav_item_color_state.xml  (I am using blue color, modify as per your own)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FF0096D6" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#FF666666" />
</selector>
```

and then "itemIconTint" and "itemTextColor"

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_color_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Yes, adding a selector is easy, and I already did that. The thing is I need to add that purple line on the top of the selected item.

Comment: okay, for that you may use a tab layout w/o title for your requirement. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489488/tabwidget-without-title